# Submitting a form in pure JS

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

How to get the formDate in the controller?

my HTML

```
<form id="myform" >
    <input type="number" name="jform[option][1]">
    <input type="number" name="jform[option][2]">
</form>
```

my js

```
var form     = document.getElementById('myform'),
    formData = new FormData(form);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', window.location.pathname+'?option=com_mycomp&task=view.mytask&id=567&'+Joomla.getOptions('csrf.token')+'=1', true);
            
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
//xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
            
xhr.send(formData);
```

Method in controller

```
public function mytask() 
{
    Session::checkToken('get') or die();
    
    $app    = Factory::getApplication();
    $id= $app->input->get('id', '0', 'INTEGER'); // it exists
        
    $form = $app->input->get('jform', array(), 'ARRAY'); // it doesn't exist
    
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this problem by simply removing the headers from the request.

```
var form     = document.getElementById('myform'),
    formData = new FormData(form);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', window.location.pathname+'?option=com_mycomp&task=view.mytask&id=567&'+Joomla.getOptions('csrf.token')+'=1', true);
            
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8'); // REMOVED!
xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');  // REMOVED!
            
xhr.send(formData);
```

**Now I get the form array as expected!**

And similarly can be done with jQuery:

```
var form     = document.getElementById('myform'),
    formData = new FormData(form);

jQuery.ajax({
    timeout: 6000,
    url: window.location.pathname+'?option=com_mycomp&task=view.mytask&id=567&'+Joomla.getOptions('csrf.token')+'=1',
    data: formData,
    type: 'post',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    success:function(result) {console.log(result)}
});
```